# Passing name of file open with Tkinter button to another function

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Experiencing some trouble using TKinter in python.  In slowly building what will be a simple program with a single master window and 4 tabs (notebooks), I have run into trouble determining how to pass a filename to function that needs it.

I have one button that opens a file dialog and allows the user to select a file and (hopefully) retrieve the file name. I have another button setup that will (hopefully) trigger a process, with the name of the chosen file passed as an argument to the method called in the command. Right now, I can trigger the open file dialog, and print the file name to the console, but I can not figure out how to pass this filename to the delineate command (which will ultimately trigger a different script with the filename as input to this script). I have it set up so that when 'Delineate' button is triggered, it displays 'Delineating....' on the window.  My goal is to be able to display 'Delineating X', where X is the opened file's name, and pass this name on to another script. If I can get it to the point where 'Delineating X' is correctly displayed, I that means the filename has been passed and I think I can do the rest...

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import Tkconstants

class Unified_Tool(ttk.Frame):
    # =============================================================================
    # Main setup options
    def __init__(self, isapp=True, name='unified_tool'):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.master.title("Unified Tool")
        self.pack(expand=Y, fill=BOTH)
        self.isapp = isapp
        self._create_widgets()
        file_name = StringVar()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._create_panels()

    def _create_panels(self):
        panel = Frame(self, name='panel')
        panel.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
        # create the notebook
        nb = ttk.Notebook(panel, name='notebook_panel')
        nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y, padx=2, pady=3)
        self._create_ca_del_tab(nb)
        #self._create_traversal_tab(nb)
        #self._create_tot_tab(nb)
        #self._create_zcc_tab(nb)

    # =============================================================================
    # Delineation tab
    def load_file(self):
        file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=([('All files', '*.*'),
                                                               ('Text files', '*.txt'),
                                                               ('CSV files', '*.csv')]))
        print file_name

    # =============================================================================
    # Delineation tab
    def _create_ca_del_tab(self, nb):

        # variable to store the filename
        del_filename = StringVar()

        # frame to hold content
        frame = ttk.Frame(nb, name='ca_delineation')

        # widgets to be displayed on 'Description' tab
        msg = ["For delineating the catchment area of a point or collection of points. In "
               "the file selection box to the left, select the input file containing the points "
               "for catchment area delineation."]
        lbl_intro = ttk.Label(frame, wraplength='4i', justify=LEFT, anchor=N,
                        text=''.join(msg))

        # button for selecting the input file
        btn_del_select_file = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        # button for triggering the task
        btn_del = ttk.Button(frame, text='Delineate!', underline=0,
                              command=lambda v=del_filename: self._delineate(del_filename))

        # label that displays the input file name
        lbl_del = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=del_filename, name='delineate')

        # position and set resize behaviour
        lbl_intro.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='new', pady=5)
        lbl_del.grid(row=1, column=1,  pady=(2,4))
        btn_del_select_file.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(2,4))
        btn_del.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(2,4))
        frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1, uniform=1)

        # add to notebook (underline = index for short-cut character)
        nb.add(frame, text='CA Delineation', underline=0, padding=2)

    def _delineate(self, v):
        v.set('Delineating....')
        self.update()
```

Comment: Please change your `class method`. check this PDF https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6xeDvpKvKAhXMthQKHVbyCwgQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nmt.edu%2Ftcc%2Fhelp%2Fpubs%2Ftkinter%2Ftkinter.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF80gkqF-dwc8-J5M-SnvJsjGFhKQ&sig2=6uY2nRD97KpYwTVZHeYv-A  Why are you trying to make things complicated? Nuke control system ?

Comment: I am building a window with four tabs - only working on the first tab right now.  Does it seem to complicated for a US that will have four different tabs, all with their buttons/labels/actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `file_name` to be an instance variable, instead of a temporary one:

```
def load_file(self):
    self.file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=([('All files', '*.*'),
                                                           ('Text files', '*.txt'),
                                                           ('CSV files', '*.csv')]))
    print self.file_name
```

Then you'll have acess to `self.filename` anywhere within the `Unified_Tool` class.

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually whenever I'm trying to do so, in my code block, it only returns ```AttributeError: 'ClassName' object has no attribute 'fileName' ```. 
Kindly help me on this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ozzius can you put the relevant sections of the code on pastebin.com for analisys?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the global variable inside the load_file function and export the file_name to other functions like this:

```
def load_file(self):
    global csv_filename
    self.file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=([('All files', '*.*'),('Text files', '*.txt'),('CSV files', '*.csv')])
    csv_filename = self.filename
    print self.file_name
```

From here onward, you can use csv_filename as the output of load_file function.